# Pseudo Codigo Xadrez

Tags: matemática, pseudocódigo

Colocaram-me um desafio para resolver através de pseudocódigo:

Um tabuleiro de xadrez apenas com o Rei e a Rainha. Qual o número mínimo e máximo de jogadas para dar xeque mate ao Rei?

Rei Preto, Rainha Branca

Sei as regras do xadrez e já joguei algumas vezes, daí até eu dizer que sei jogar xadrez, vai uma longa distância.

Comment: Um rei e uma rainha preta e tb um rei e uma rainha branca?

Comment: Não impuseram as cores, mas já agora haverá diferenças nas cores do Rei e Rainha?

Comment: Pergunto pq isso interfere, se ambos estiverem com uma rainha o numero de movimentos é X, se somente uma cor possuir essa vantagem, o numero de movimentos e outro. Um lugar para simular é o https://nextchessmove.com/ mas se a disposição for a inicial (https://nextchessmove.com/?fen=3qk3%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F3QK3+w+-+-+0+1&flipped=false), logo de cara uma rainha captura a outra, e em 2 movimentos vc acaba so com os reis, ai é impossível dar mate

Comment: Você tem que detalhar melhor o seu problema, tá cheio de brecha para interpretações.

Comment: `Cenário 1: Rei Preto, Rainha Branca Cenário 2: Rei Branco, Rainha Preta` Você percebe que não há diferenças nos cálculos dos dois cenários, não é mesmo? Em ambos os casos tem um rei e uma rainha inimigos, a cor tanto faz.

Comment: Post editado. Obrigado @Math. Só tenho esta informação. É possível elaborar uma resolução perante este problema?

Comment: Não é possível resolver só com essas informações - também é necessário saber a posição iniciao das peças. E tem certeza que é só rei preto / rainha branca? Não seria rei preto / rei + rainha branca (ou vice-versa)? Se uma cor não tem o rei, então por definição das regras do xadrez ela já perdeu.

Comment: Somente Rei preto e Rainha Branca. Para que o Rei tenha mais possíveis jogadas terá de estar no meio do tabuleiro, certo?

Comment: Se for somente a rainha branca contra o rei preto (o que vai contra as regras do xadrez), então a rainha **não consegue dar o cheque-mate sozinha no rei**. Talvez haja um [*stalemate* ("rei afogado")](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rei_afogado), ou o jogo seguirá até acabar o tempo (ou a paciência dos jogadores).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Da forma que a pergunta está formulada, não há informações suficientes para resolver o problema. Mas assumindo o seguinte:

- Não são somente um rei e uma rainha (de cores opostos), mas sim um rei de uma cor e um par (rei + rainha) da outra cor
- Para simplificar a explicação abaixo, assumindo que há um rei preto (K), e um rei (k) e uma rainha (q) brancos

O número mínimo de jogadas é zero - se a configuração inicial do tabuleiro já estiver num estado de cheque-mate. Por exemplo (vez do preto):

```
/-------------------------------\
|   |   |   |   | K |   |   | q |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   | k |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|-------------------------------|
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
\-------------------------------/
```

Ou um, se for uma jogada antes dessa.

O número máximo vai depender da estratégia que o jogador das peças brancas está usando para encurralar o rei preto. Se o jogador não tiver nenhuma estratégia e mover as peças aleatoriamente, o número máximo pode tender ao infinito.

Há algumas estratégias de fim de jogo para esse cenário (K vs k+q). Se o jogador tiver usando uma delas (por exemplo, http://www.wikihow.com/Mate-With-King-and-Queen-Vs-King), o número máximo dependerá de onde estão inicialmente as três peças no tabuleiro - como o rei branco precisa chegar "perto" do preto, se ele estiver mais longe o número de jogadas será maior. [Mas no máximo, o número de jogadas antes do cheque-mate será 10](http://www.chessguru.net/end_game/queen_checkmate/).

Comment: +1, só é uma pena que a explicação não usou o [xadrez do Mário](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91w-uj9SRcL._UL1500_.jpg) :'(

Comment: @Math, você quer dizer que eu deveria usar esse tabuleiro: http://imgur.com/AczKFFE?

Comment: Perfeito! Encurralaram o bowser!!

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @carlosfigueira.